# Which MYSql Join to use - I have 12 tables, 1 for each month of the year, i want to join them all to have 1 table for the whole year

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I just want to have 1 large table with the data for the whole year so i can manipulate the whole year at the same time instead of having to repeat the same processes 12 times.

I thought it would be a simple inner join, but that just duplicates the rows from (ex. January and February) next to eachother instead of stacking into their respective columns. all columns are the exact same.

Comment: It's not entirely clear without seeing an example, but it sounds like you don't need a join, you want a `union` (`union all`, since you know the data is unique)

Answer (score 2):

I know almost nothing about what you're doing, but - to me - data model looks **wrong**. That should've been only one table at the first place, while date column would be used to distinguish different months. Furthermore, saying that you'd like to work with the whole year's data - I hope that you won't be creating another set of 12 tables for the next year (and every year to come).

Anyway: presuming that tables' description is the same, you'd then use union set operator to put all data together. Though, instead of doing it in every query you're about to write afterwards, consider creating a view, e.g.

```
create view v_data as
select id, name, address, month, amount from january
union all
select id, name, address, month, amount from february
union all
...
select id, name, address, month, amount from december;
```

Then you'd just use that view in queries, e.g.

```
select sum(amount)
from v_data
where month in (1, 3, 8)
```